# World Building Podcast Episode #2: Aaaand Cut!

Tags: discussion, podcast

So we published **Episode 2** today and though biased I have to say it is pretty entertaining.

We chatted with Monica about her story, discussed questions from the site, built a world together and offered a few personal recommendations...all in a somewhat *verbose* manner.

Hope that you all enjoy it, please feel free to leave comments here or on YouTube and let us know what you think, and feel free to subscribe as well.

**Thanks to my co-hosts Monica, Green and Nex**

---

**The episode can be found here:**  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvJN4s-o3LM

**And the full description:**

Episode 2 of The Factory Floor, a podcast about building worlds and filling them with interesting things.

In this episode we introduce a new guest and co-host who has taken some world building work and turned it into an actual story!

The World Building at Stack Exchange: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/
and the blog:  http://www.medium.com/universe-factory

- Welcome and introducing Monica:  00:00:00 – 00:04:05
- Warm-up, playing gods:  00:04:06 – 00:41:44
- Interview with Monica:  00:41:45 – 01:05:43

Link to The Sisters' War:  https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-a718622d808f#.royh1wl3x

- Questions from the site:  01:05:44 – 01:43:50

What would a battle between supercomputers be like with the battleground being the internet? [What would a battle between supercomputers be like with the battleground being the internet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27231/what-would-a-battle-between-supercomputers-be-like-with-the-battleground-being-t)

If magic is real, can it be true that rational scientific thought should exclude it? [If magic is real, can it be true that rational scientific thought should exclude it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13364/if-magic-is-real-can-it-be-true-that-rational-scientific-thought-should-exclude)

Can you add a mini moon to Earth? [Can you add a mini moon to Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/can-you-add-a-mini-moon-to-earth)

How can I develop names for my fantasy land?  [How can I develop names for my fantasy land?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48622/how-can-i-develop-names-for-my-fantasy-land)

International pronunciation alphabet:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet

On a side note be nice and donate to Wikipedia

XKCD:  http://xkcd.com/
     Thing Explainer:  Complicated Stuff in Simple Words [https://www.amazon.com/Thing-Explainer-Complicated-Stuff-Simple/dp/0544668251/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480450409&sr=8-1&keywords=the+thing+explainer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0544668251)

- Recommendations:  01:43:51 – 01:53:59

Rainbow 6 Siege:  http://store.steampowered.com/app/359550/

The Three Body Problem by Cixin Liu: [https://www.amazon.com/Three-Body-Problem-Cixin-Liu/dp/0765382032/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1480451507&sr=1-1&keywords=the+three+body+problem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765382032)

The Hero with a Thousand Faces by Joseph Campbell: [https://www.amazon.com/Thousand-Faces-Collected-Joseph-Campbell/dp/1577315936/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1480451578&sr=1-1&keywords=the+hero+with+a+thousand+faces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1577315936)

Microscope: [https://www.amazon.com/Microscope-Ben-Robbins/dp/0983277907/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480452022&sr=8-1&keywords=microscope+game](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0983277907)

The Wiz Biz by Rick Cook: [https://www.amazon.com/Wiz-Biz-Rick-Cook/dp/0671878468/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1480451685&sr=1-1&keywords=Wiz+Biz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671878468)